# Is there a way to detect which workspace you are currently in from the command line?

Tags: gnome, command-line, workspaces

I'm trying to figure out how to get the workspace number from a terminal script in gnome.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you aren't using Compiz, you can use [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) [image: Install xdotool].

Example:

```
xdotool get_desktop
```

This will return `0` if run from the first workspace, `1` if run from the second etc.

Answer (score 10):

An old, and answered thread, but I was just after the same info. You can do this with standard xorg tools with:

```
xprop -root -notype _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am using it to create a separate tmux session for each Gnome workspace. I just need to use this instead:

```xprop -root -notype _NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP```

Answer (score 7):

If you *are* using compiz, this will be a bit more difficult.

**edit:** this now works both with and without compiz, finally...

I wrote a "little" python script to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
getoutput = lambda x: Popen(x, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
compiz_running = list(i for i in getoutput(("ps", "-aef", )).split("\n")
    if "compiz --replace" in i and not "grep" in i) != []

if compiz_running:
    # get the position of the current workspace
    ws = list(int(i.strip(",")) for i in  getoutput(("xprop", "-root",
        "-notype", "_NET_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT", )).split()[-2:])
    # get the number of horizontal and vertical workspaces
    hsize = int(getoutput(("gconftool",
        "--get", "/apps/compiz/general/screen0/options/hsize", )))
    vsize = int(getoutput(("gconftool",
        "--get", "/apps/compiz/general/screen0/options/vsize", )))
    # get the dimentions of a single workspace
    x, y = list(int(i) for i in getoutput(("xwininfo", "-root",
        "-stats", )).split("geometry ")[1].split("+")[0].split("x"))
    # enumerate workspaces
    workspaces, n = [], 0
    for j in range(vsize):
        for i in range(hsize):
            workspaces.append([n, [x*i, y*j, ], ])
            n += 1
    print list(i for i in workspaces if i[1] == ws)[0][0]
# if compiz is not running
else: # this code via @DoR
    print getoutput(("xdotool", "get_desktop", )).strip()
```

Save this somewhere and mark it as executable. This will output just a number between `0` and the number of workspaces.

This is how the enumeration looks like:

```
+---+---+
| 0 | 1 |
+---+---+
| 2 | 3 |
+---+---+
```

You've got to install [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) [image: Install xdotool] for this to work in case compiz is disabled.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to remove " --replace" from the compiz_running test, and also seemed to get the wrong value for vsize (1 vs 2) when running this on Precise 12.04, even though ccsm General Options said my Desktop Size / Vertical Virtual Size is 2.

Answer (score 3):

Without installing anything and if you are using metacity, you can use this :

```
python -c "import wnck; s=wnck.screen_get_default(); s.force_update(); w=s.get_active_workspace();  w_num=w.get_number(); print(w_num);" 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with Unity, the accepted answer

```
 xdotool get_desktop_viewport
```

doesn't work - it always returns 0.  I guess the screen is configured as a really big viewport of which only part is visible.  The alternative is a bit tricky since you have to know the size of your workspace.  I.e.:

```
 xdotool get_desktop_viewport
```

will return something like "1600 0" if you are in the upper right workspace.  The first number is probably the width of the largest display you have.